# Setting Seed to reproduce same results every time

Tags: python, loops, random-seed

I have the following code, but even though I have set the seed the result differs every time I run it.

```
boostraps_num = 1200
boostraps_auc =[]
n = len(y_predprob)

np.random.RandomState(3)
for i in range(boostraps_num):
    index = np.random.randint(0, n, n)
    score = roc_auc_score(y[index], y_predprob[index])
    boostraps_auc.append(score)
```

I also tried using the following but it just made each number the same.

```
np.random.RandomState(3).randint(0, n, n)
```

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're not using the new `RandomState` random-number generator you create at all; you create an object and throw it away.

In the second example, you create a new `RandomState` for each random number, the RNG always has the same initial state, and you only ever use it once, so you always get the same number.

```
import numpy as np

y_predprob = [1, 2, 3]
boostraps_num = 15
boostraps_auc = []
n = len(y_predprob)

rng = np.random.RandomState(3)
for i in range(boostraps_num):
    index = rng.randint(0, n, n)
    boostraps_auc.append(index)
print(boostraps_auc)
```

will always print the same result.